# A way to verify PayPal Account Status is Verfied using PHP

Tags: php, paypal

Basically I want my users to associate PayPal account in their accounts for identify verification purposes. I am developing a marketplace site and wanted to integrate paypal as my identity verification procedure.

Is there a way to verify email address, first name and last name using PHP like using `$_GET` variables or `$_POST` variables? If there is can you show me how?

I tried search and I get Adaptive Accounts `GetVerifiedStatus` API. But that totally new to me, I don't know where and how to start.

Comment: do you mean that the verification will take place after the purchase?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac no.. verification will take place upon a registration of account.

Comment: so the users will register through paypal login?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac no.. basically when registering.. the user will enter their first name, last name and email.. the email used should be paypal. Now I want to verify if the email along with the first and last name is a verified paypal account.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless they sign in to paypal at the same time as they register to your site. Adaptive payments could help?

Comment: Why not just make the user sign in with their paypal account? 
It's fairly straight forward https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet here is to make them start, but not complete, an Express Checkout. A normal Express Checkout (referencing Classic but REST works the same way) looks like this

1. SetExpressCheckout - Tell PayPal you want to authorize $1.00 and have them log in and authorize the payment
2. [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) - Take the token from step 1 and get their PayPal account details. Included in this is `PAYERSTATUS`, which will tell you if their PayPal account is verified or not
3. DoExpressCheckout - You won't do this, but this is where you finish the process and get funds. Since the data you want is in Step 2, just ignore it and the session will expire.

Comment: There should be a better way then ignore is there not a way to terminate the transaction?

Comment: EC sessions expire in 3 hours. There's no API calls to abort the EC process that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement GetVerifiedStatus API to determine whether the specified Paypal account's status is verified or unverified.

To use that API, you need to submit the application request to Paypal for approval first. Submission portal link [here](https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications).

Then use the GetVerifiedStatus API call directly, refer to API request fields,[link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/).

Sample SDK download [link](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php).